# Enabling brcmfmac driver for Wifi on a Macbook Pro

Tags: linux, networking, broadcom

So I'm trying to install Void Linux on my Macbook Pro however it doesn't appear to come with the brcmfmac module. There are a bunch of `.bin` brcmfmac files in `/usr/lib/firmware` but nothing in `/usr/lib/modules`. I'm not really knowledgable about how this works so I'd appreciate some guidance. Void Linux does come with the brcmsmac module but that doesn't work for me.

```
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4371-pcie.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4366b-pcie.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.ap.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43570-pcie.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43569.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4354-sdio.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4350c2-pcie.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43362-sdio.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4335-sdio.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4334-sdio.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4329-sdio.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b0-sdio.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43236b.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43143.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b5-sdio.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43143-sdio.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4339-sdio.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin
/usr/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43242a.bi

/usr/lib/modules/4.5.2_1/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmsmac/brcmsmac.ko.gz
```